# How do I create a game with Node.js that has multiple servers but only one URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm relatively new to node.js and I'm trying to make a game that only uses one accessible URL but has multiple pages. In my game I'm going to be using the socket.io and express modules. I really want to have one URL that the client will access which will give them the title screen and then the menu page. There will be buttons on this page which will send the client to different servers that run games. The only way that I can think of how to do this is to have multiple servers running on different pages and have the buttons contain links. I know that it is possible to have multiple servers running on the same URL. One example of this is the diep.io online game. Is it possible to accomplish this with node.js? If so, how would I go about making this happen? Should I be using ports to create these pages?

Comment: This really isn't a question for Stack Overflow as it is really just asking for advice/tutorial information and there is no one way to accomplish this. It's too broad, opinion based and off-topic for us. Better to try Google.

Comment: I have searched and searched and I can't find anything so I was hoping someone would be able to help here.

Comment: Basically describing a single page application which is as much client side programming as back end

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you're talking about is referred to as "horizontal scaling" where instead of having one beefy server you have many lower-end servers that run the same code.

Or since you're using Socket.io there's a concept of "rooms" that you can use.

My memory on both of these topics is a bit cloudy so I can't help much more, but you should be able to Google them now.

This channel has tutorials on JS / Node game dev:

https://www.youtube.com/user/RainingChain/featured